# Regex Expression for Name followed by number

Tags: regex

Can anyone help with the following Regex validation for a Google form?

Smith 46300
Trent-Brown 86500

The validation being:
"Name" Case (if such a term exists) - initial capitals required and hyphenations allowed.
Final 6 characters must be space followed by any 5 numerals.

Many thanks.

Comment: I got as far as this:^(?:[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*))(?:\s+[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*|[a-z]*))*$ but then got lost in trying to add the "-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying something so complicated?

Why not just 
`^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-)*[A-Z][a-z]+ \d+$`

See: examples here: https://regex101.com/r/j14GL6/1

If you want only max. 1 hyphen then use instead `^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-)?[A-Z][a-z]+ \d+$`

Comment: I think that I had been close to that before, but I was put off by Google Forms coming up with a warning in red "Must match Pattern" as soon as I started entering data. I thought that this must mean that it was not matching the validation, however it probably was. The warning should really only come up when it fails the validation.

Comment: @Andy an upvote and mark as correct would be nice then

Comment: Fallenhero - I have realised that the pattern doesn't match - it allows for less than 5 numbers at the end. I was going to work out the solution before replying.

Comment: in fact:^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+-)?[A-Z][a-z]+ \d\d\d\d\d+$ is the solution. Many thanks any for getting me 99% there.

Comment: @Andy: don't use `\d\d\d\d\d+` that is ugly and means 5 or more digits. you want `\d{5}`